# How do I print a floating-point value for later scanning with perfect accuracy?

Tags: c, floating-point, precision, numeric

Suppose I have a floating-point value of type `float` or `double` (i.e. 32 or 64 bits on typical machines). I want to print this value as text (e.g. to the standard output stream), and then later, in some other process, scan it back in - with `fscanf()` if I'm using C, or perhaps with `istream::operator>>()` if I'm using C++. But - I need the scanned float to end up being *exactly*,  identical to the original value (up to equivalent representations of the same value). Also, the printed value should be easily readable - to a human - as floating-point, i.e. I don't want to print 0x42355316 and reinterpret that as a 32-bit float.

How should I do this? I'm assuming the standard library of (C and C++) won't be sufficient, but perhaps I'm wrong. I suppose that a sufficient number of decimal digits might be able to guarantee an error that's underneath the precision threshold - but that's not the same as guaranteeing the rounding/truncation will happen just the way I want it.

Notes:

- The scanning does not having to be perfectly accurate w.r.t. the value it scans, only the original value.
- If it makes it easier, you may assume the value is a number and is not infinity.
- denormal support is desired but not required; still if we get a denormal, failure should be conspicuous.

Comment: Would you consider using the `%a` format *easily readable as floating-point*? Or its C++ iostream equivalent?

Comment: No @AdrianMole. @einpoklum said `I don't want to print 0x42355316 and reinterpret that as a 32-bit float`

Comment: @ShadiNaif But there would be no need to *reinterpret* anything! Using the `%a` format with `scanf` will read the value *directly* into a `double` variable. And an IEEE number can be ***accurately*** represented (always) in hex-float format, as there is no implied base conversion to/from decimal.

Comment: Yes @AdrianMole, but as far I can understand from the question; it must be readable as a normal number, not Hexa. Please correct me if I'm wrong einpoklum

Comment: @ShadiNaif Which is why I asked in my first comment. Does "easily readable" mean for a human or for the computer?

Comment: @ShadiNaif I took OP's comment to mean they want print the *value* and not the *representation*.

Comment: @AdrianMole: You can add that as an answer, even though it's not really what I want, because others may find this solution relevant despite my preference.

Comment: Three answers already - none of us waited for your clarification!  ‎

Comment: Maybe you can do both? Print the number in both `%f` and `%a` formats, and tell the human to read the one and the machine to read the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you should use the `%a` format with `fprintf` and `fscanf`. This is what it was designed for, and the C standard requires it to work (reproduce the original number) if the implementation uses binary floating-point.

Failing that, you should print a `float` with at least `FLT_DECIMAL_DIG` significant digits and a `double` with at least `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG` significant digits. Those constants are defined in `<float.h>` and are defined:

> … number of decimal digits, *n*, such that any floating-point number with *p* radix *b* digits can be rounded to a floating-point number with *n* decimal digits and back again without change to the value,… [*b* is the base used for the floating-point format, defined in `FLT_RADIX`, and *p* is the number of base-*b* digits in the format.]

For example:

```
    printf("%.*g\n", FLT_DECIMAL_DIG, 1.f/3);
```

or:

```
#define QuoteHelper(x)  #x
#define Quote(x)        QuoteHelper(x)
…
    printf("%." Quote(FLT_DECIMAL_DIG) "g\n", 1.f/3);
```

In C++, these constants are defined in `<limits>` as `std::numeric_limits<Type>::max_digits10`, where `Type` is `float` or `double` or another floating-point type.

Note that the C standard only recommends that such a round-trip through a decimal numeral work; it does not require it. For example, C 2018 5.2.4.2.2 15 says, under the heading “Recommended practice”:

> Conversion from (at least) `double` to decimal with `DECIMAL_DIG` digits and back should be the identity function. [`DECIMAL_DIG` is the equivalent of `FLT_DECIMAL_DIG` or `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG` for the widest floating-point format supported in the implementation.]

In contrast, if you use `%a`, and `FLT_RADIX` is a power of two (meaning the implementation uses a floating-point base that is two, 16, or another power of two), then C standard requires that the result of scanning the numeral produced with `%a` equals the original number.

Answer (score 2):

> I need the scanned float to end up being *exactly*, identical to the original value.

As already pointed out in the other answers, that can be achieved with the `%a` format specifier.

> Also, the printed value should be easily readable - to a human - as floating-point, i.e. I don't want to print 0x42355316 and reinterpret that as a 32-bit float.

That's more tricky and subjective. The first part of the string that `%a` produces is in fact a fraction composed by hexadecimal digits, so that an output like `0x1.4p+3` may take some time to be parsed as `10` by a human reader.

An option could be to print *all* the decimal digits needed to represent the floating-point value, but there may be a lot of them. Consider, for example the value 0.1, its closest representation as a 64-bit float may be

```
0x1.999999999999ap-4  ==  0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625
```

While `printf("%.*lf\n", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG, 01);` (see e.g. Eric's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62982579/4944425)) would print

```
0.10000000000000001   // If DBL_DECIMAL_DIG == 17
```

My proposal is somewhere in the middle. Similarly to what `%a` does, we can exactly represent any floating-point value with radix 2 as a fraction multiplied by 2 raised to some integer power. We can transform that fraction into a whole number (increasing the exponent accordingly) and print it as a decimal value.

```
0x1.999999999999ap-4 --> 1.999999999999a16 * 2-4  --> 1999999999999a16 * 2-56 
                     --> 720575940379279410 * 2-56
```

That whole number has a limited number of digits (it's < 2<sup>53</sup>), but the result it's still an exact representation of the original `double` value.

The following snippet is a proof of concept, without any check for corner cases. The format specifier `%a` separates the mantissa and the exponent with a `p` character (as in "... multiplied by two raised to the *Power* of..."), I'll use a `q` instead, for no particular reason other than using a different symbol.

The value of the mantissa will also be reduced (and the exponent raised accordingly), removing all the trailing zero-bits. The idea beeing that `5q+1` (parsed as 5<sub>10</sub> * 2<sup>1</sup>) should be more "easily" identified as `10`, rather than `2814749767106560q-48`.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void to_my_format(double x, char *str)
{
    int exponent;
    double mantissa = frexp(x, &exponent);
    long long m = 0;
    if ( mantissa ) {
        exponent -= 52;
        m = (long long)scalbn(mantissa, 52);
        // A reduced mantissa should be more readable
        while (m  &&  m % 2 == 0) {
            ++exponent;
            m /= 2;
        }
    }
    sprintf(str, "%lldq%+d", m, exponent);
    //                ^
    // Here 'q' is used to separate the mantissa from the exponent  
}

double from_my_format(char const *str)
{
    char *end;
    long long mantissa = strtoll(str, &end, 10);
    long exponent = strtol(str + (end - str + 1), &end, 10);
    return scalbn(mantissa, exponent);
}

int main(void)
{
    double tests[] = { 1, 0.5, 2, 10, -256, acos(-1), 1000000, 0.1, 0.125 };
    size_t n = (sizeof tests) / (sizeof *tests);
    
    char num[32];
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i ) {
        to_my_format(tests[i], num);
        double x = from_my_format(num);
        printf("%22s%22a ", num, tests[i]);
        if ( tests[i] != x )
            printf(" *** %22a *** Round-trip failed\n", x);
        else
            printf("%58.55g\n", x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Testable [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/e1Pa5pVQKzrk4xR9).

Generally, the improvement in readability is admitedly little to none, surely a matter of opinion.

Comment: I'm guessing `p` instead of `e` means "times 2-to-the-power-of"? But then, what is `q` supposed to signify?

Comment: @einpoklum I apologize, it hasn't a particular meaning other than beeing a different symbol. Of course, if someone would consider this kind of representation they'd better come up with a more meaningful one.

Comment: No need to apologize, just edit the answer to say what `p` and `q` signify... I already gave you my +1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `%a` format specifier to print the value as hexadecimal floating point.  Note that this is not the same as reinterpreting the `float` as an integer and printing the integer value.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    float x;
    scanf("%f", &x);
    printf("x=%.7f\n", x);

    char str[20];
    sprintf(str, "%a", x);
    printf("str=%s\n", str);

    float y;
    sscanf(str, "%f", &y);
    printf("y=%.7f\n", y);
    printf("x==y: %d\n", (x == y));

    return 0;
}
```

With an input of 4, this outputs:

```
x=4.0000000
str=0x1p+2
y=4.0000000
x==y: 1
```

With an input of 3.3, this outputs:

```
x=3.3000000
str=0x1.a66666p+1
y=3.3000000
x==y: 1
```

As you can see from the output, the `%a` format specifier prints in exponential format with the significand in hex and the exponent in decimal.  This format can then be converted directly back to the exact same value as demonstrated by the equality check.